# Image Files in Mongo DB as URI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, webpack

So, I am building a Portfolio Application- and have a question.

Currently, I am saving the URL to the project picture in the mongodb as "`../to/file/path/logo.svg"`
and then using Redux and Axios to pull it into the state. Nodejs back end. (Let me know if you need any more information).

Problem is, when I do it this way and not import it directly into react like:

```
import project from '../../img/projects/time_keeper.svg';
```

Webpack doesnt see them and these file paths are not working.

What is the best idea to handle this? am I thinking too much about it?

Any help would be great!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing image URL? You can only store the image name and when you are getting the image from MongoDB you can concat the image path like this.
Here I am defining my server path in "URL" and then I concat image path and in the user, I am getting the data.

```
URL+'api/uploads/employee/'+user.image;
```

Comment: this is kinda what I need - the images are saved from me onto the computer. I saved images I created in img/projects/time_keeper.svg <-- when I run the build on my react app, it doesnt bring this file with it. Could I just add the file after? or maybe I am not understand what the build function does.